# Polar coordinates used to evaluate a function containing a branch cut

Tags: complex-analysis, polar-coordinates, branch-cuts

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how to approach these kinds of problems, if anyone could explain the approach, it would be really helpful. The problem is as follows:

The function $f(z)$ is given by

$$f(z)=(z+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}\ln{\left(z-\sqrt{3}\right)}$$

The branch of this function is chosen such that

$$-\frac{3\pi}{2}<\arg{(z+1)}\leq \frac{\pi}{2} \\
-\frac{2\pi}{3}<\arg{\left(z-\sqrt{3}\right)}\leq \frac{4\pi}{3}$$

Draw a clearly labelled diagram showing the branch cuts and the polar coordinates used to evaluate the function.

Comment: Are they asking you to plot the domain?

Comment: To my understanding I essentially need to write the polar coordinates that would be used to evaluate the function above and below the branch cut and draw a vector in the complex plain of length $r_1$ at an angle $\theta_1$ to the horizontal that represents $(z+1)^{1/2}$ and the same for $\ln{(z-\sqrt{3})}$ where I define the moduli $r_1$, $r_2$ and the polar angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ above and below the branch cut, i.e. at $X \pm i0$ and also mark on the diagram where the branch cuts are located.